# Finding MaxiMin Solution of Function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, minimax

I would like to find the maximin solution of a function `f` in Matlab (below is the definition of maximin)

[image: MaxiMin]

`x` and `y` are both real vectors and `f` is smooth but 'quite complex to calculate' (it is formed from the output of a neural network).

I tried an alternating approach of holding `x` constant and minimising for `y` and then holding `y` constant and maximising for `x` but this did not converge and instead oscillated.

I believe you can use genetic algorithms to solve the problem but firstly could not see how to do it in Matlab and secondly thought it may be a waste of the fact that `f` is smooth.

I have both the Optimization and Global Optimization toolbox. What is the best way to solve this problem in Matlab?

Comment: Can you get access to derivative information about 'f'? If so, this will open up powerful methods to solve the problem that are not available if 'f' is a black box function.

Comment: Can you give us some information about the function?